# Are there any linguistic toollkits for PowerShell or .NET?

Tags: nlp, computational-linguistics, tools

In the past when I was an active Python coder I played a bit with NLTK and learned some basic linguistic terminology. But meanwhile I shifted to PowerShell and I have abandoned coding in Python.

Every now and than I'm searching for linguistic projects in PowerShell context, but until now I didn't find anything.

Are there other sources not based on script languages I should consider?

Comment: Please change "considerate" (an adjective) to "consider" (a verb). Hurts the eyes...

Comment: @bernd_k: What is your objective: (1) Finding a PowerShell version NLTK? (2) Linguistic related scripts written in PowerShell and/or .NET Framework? (3) Learning about linguistic? (4) Doing natural language processing research using computational linguistics tools? (5) Something not listed... since if it's more than one of those, each are of those are likely separate questions.

Comment: @blunders it's mainly (1), but I have little hope, that such a thing exists.

Comment: This would be an excellent question for http://bit.ly/u4lZUG.

Comment: Does NLTK work in IronPython?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, there are no "truly equivalent" implementations of NLTK in PowerShell.**

Here's a [list of natural language processing toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits) which is sortable by the computer language they were implemented in.

Answer (score 1):

This is **Stanford NLP Software for .NET**

> The Stanford NLP Group makes parts of Natural Language Processing software available to everyone. These are statistical NLP toolkits for various major computational linguistics problems. They can be incorporated into applications with human language technology needs

https://github.com/sergey-tihon/Stanford.NLP.NET

https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/

Answer (score 0):

Here is NLTK .NET wrapper. You will be needed to install IronPython to make it work.
Instructions are there:

https://github.com/nrcpp/NltkNet

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! This post would benefit from adding further details. Being a one-line post, it may attract downvotes and criticism. Please [edit] it to add further relevant information — preferably with references to credible sources.